# What is wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion

[Is it legal to have unpaid volunteer moderators (or other types of volunteers) on a for-profit community website?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/42717/is-it-legal-to-have-unpaid-volunteer-moderators-or-other-types-of-volunteers-o/46007?noredirect=1#comment87954_46007)

DaleM was simply mad that I disagreed with him when he was obviously wrong. The question was can a commercial site use unpaid moderators.

DaleM is an unpaid mod on a commercial site just by being here! He said that isn't legal. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Robbing banks is illegal - by your logic there are no such thing as bank robbers

Comment: @DaleM what? lol

Comment: @Putvi It seems like you're feeling frustrated by your inability to grasp some pretty basic concepts. Although you "know a real judge," it may be that this relationship hasn't fully prepared you to competently answer questions on a broad cross-section of topics. You might find it beneficial to spend some more asking questions instead of answering them.

Comment: I can grasp  any topic lol. You would do well from thinking other people can't and realize that you are wrong at times @bdb484

Comment: Not to be rude, but it's one thing to read some internet articles and form an opinion of how you think it's really done and it's another to be there irl.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll give it all the weight it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

That wasn't an answer, it was an unnecessarily sarcastic meta comment. It has no place on Stack Exchange, let alone posted that way.

I note that this "answer" had also received two downvotes and at least one rude/abusive flag inside of seven hours, so the accusation of DaleM acting on emotion is not only rude but totally illogical.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude to you NIJ, but DaleM's answer was obvioulsy false and he closed mine.